# Is Virgin Galactic still targeting high speed suborbital flights, or just space tourism?

Tags: commercial, virgin-galactic

A long time ago I followed the development of Space Ship One and subsequently Space Ship Two.  At the time I remember someone (I believe it was Branson) saying that one of the primary uses of their future suborbital program would be as a sort of replacement for the Concorde, to allow high speed travel across the globe for CEOs and other high-power businessmen.

I've just started doing some catchup reading now.  Everything I see now related to Space Ship Two talks about space tourism, while I also see they are talking about a Mach 3 aircraft.  The latter is only set to fly at about 50k feet, while Space Ship Two hit (I believe) about 5x that height.  This will provide vastly different user experiences, as well as, I'm sure, regulatory difficulties.

Has Virgin Galactic given up the idea of using Space Ship Two to provide suborbital flights to different locations for high speed travel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in May of this year, they had not given up.

The [article](https://techcrunch.com/2020/05/05/virgin-galactic-is-partnering-with-nasa-to-develop-supersonic-point-to-point-air-travel/?guccounter=1) *Virgin Galactic is partnering with NASA to develop supersonic point-to-point air travel* states that they have signed a Space Act agreement with NASA on this topic.

There is a [press release](https://www.virgingalactic.com/articles/virgin-galactic-enters-space-act-agreement-with-nasa-to-advance-high-mach-technologies/) on the Virgin Galactic webpage, but it is largely content-free.

I did not see it on the [NASA web site listing Space Act Agreements](https://www.nasa.gov/partnerships/about.html) though.  The page may not be a comprehensive list.